# java - method and passing variable from jInternalFrame to jFrame

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, jinternalframe

and I have the following problem.
i am new in java and i am trying to send a variable which is user_id, from JInternalFrame to JFrame.

I can't use constructor because JFrame is the main program activated at startup and containing jDesktoPane

so i was trying to use the methods, however, can't do it (i posted the two methods, both of which I tried but did not work)

Method A)

Code in jFrame (Main_window)

```
public javax.swing.JTextField getID() {
  return jTextField_id;
}

public void setID(javax.swing.JTextField ID) 
{
jTextField_id = ID;
}
```

code in jInternalFrame

```
Main_window send = new Main_window(); 
send.getID().setText("123");
```

Method B)

Code in jFrame (Main_window) 
USER_ID is a variable accesible in any place of jFrame

```
public void setID(String ID) 
{
USER_ID = ID;
}
```

code in jInternalFrame

```
Main_window send = new Main_window(); 
send.setID("123");
```

both method don't change anything but have no errors in compilation

if there is any other way of doing it pls tell me :)

sorry for my language and grammar. 
if this help i use Eclipse compilator

this code worked for me, ty for help

```
public void set_ID(String ID) 
{
    Test_JF mainWindow = (Test_JF) this.getTopLevelAncestor();;
    mainWindow.setID(ID);
}
```

activated by set_ID("1234");

Comment: `new Main_Window(); ...` looks suspiciously like creating a new instance, instead of calling `setID()` in the actual main window.

Comment: yes i know but i need to send a id that is in jinternalframe so i must use it in that frame, that jinternalframe is a logging page

Comment: Like kiheru said, you are setting the id on a new instance. Possible solutions would be to declare id as static, or pass a reference of the JFrame in the constructor of the JInternalFrame

Comment: hmm that sounds logic, can you pls show me a simple example how i can do this? i am newbie in window application programing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your JInternalFrame class:

```
JFrame mainWindow = (JFrame)this.getTopLevelAncestor();
mainWindow.setID("123");
```

Comment: i got error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: That doesn´t really give much information. Have you debugged it? Which variable was null? You´ll have to show the whole code in order for anyone to be able to says where the error is.

Comment: my program is a little to big, in 2 min i do small test equivalent and put it here

Answer (score 0):

ok so here is smaller version of my program
"Test_JF" is a main JFrame and "Test_JIF" is a JInternalFrame

here is TestJF

```
public class Test_JF extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField user_id;

String USER_ID;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test_JF frame = new Test_JF();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Test_JF() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 750, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    user_id = new JTextField();
    user_id.setBounds(338, 11, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(user_id);
    user_id.setColumns(10);

    JButton button_user_id = new JButton("fill user id");
    button_user_id.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            user_id.setText(USER_ID);
        }
    });
    button_user_id.setBounds(239, 10, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(button_user_id);

    JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
    desktopPane.setBounds(10, 56, 714, 395);
    contentPane.add(desktopPane);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
            Test_JIF Open = new Test_JIF();
            desktopPane.add(Open);
            Open.show();
        }
    });

}

public void setID(String ID) 
{
USER_ID = ID;
}}
```

here is TestJIF

```
public class Test_JIF extends JInternalFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Test_JIF frame = new Test_JIF();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public Test_JIF() {
    Test_JF mainWindow = (Test_JF)this.getTopLevelAncestor();
    setBounds(100, 100, 328, 199);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton button_send = new JButton("New button");
    button_send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainWindow.setID("123");
        }
    });
    button_send.setBounds(111, 73, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(button_send);

}}
```

i clear imports here(on web) so it will be cleaner

Comment: 1. This should be an edit to the question, not an answer. 2. At the stage when you're calling `getTopLevelAncestor()` the internal window does not have one yet. The simplest would be passing the top level frame as a constructor parameter, so it would be available to be used in the `Test_JIF` constructor. 3. `null` layouts are a bad idea, and lead to no end of problems. Use layout managers instead, that's how swing is designed to be used.

Comment: 1. sorry for that 2.it sounds perfect but how i can get frame parameter? and how pass is, as what?

Comment: nvm with help of everyone here i done method what can send data :)  i puted it in main post

Comment: To pass the window as a constructor parameter, make the `Test_JIF` constructor `public Test_JIF(Test_JF mainWindow)` - see the java [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). And in main window when creating the internal frame, create it as `new Test_JIF(Test_JF.this)` (the unusual way to refer to `this` is because otherwise `this` would refer to the action listener).